# Error using HTTP Post

Tags: android, http-post

I got an error using `HttpPost` for sending an MMS in Android.

In the Logcat it says:

> ERROR/Here(447): ---------Error-----Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

My sample code:

```
String url = "myurl";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(url, new Integer(90000)); // 90 second
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    File SDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(SDCard, "1.png");
    FileEntity entity;
    entity = new FileEntity(file,"binary/octet-stream");
    entity.setChunked(true);
    post.setEntity(entity);
    post.addHeader("Header", "UniqueName");
    Log.i("MMSHTTP","----post---------------"+post);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.e("Here",
              "--------Error--------Response Status line code:" + response.getStatusLine());
    }
    else 
    {
        // Here every thing is fine.
    }

    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity == null) {
        Log.e("Here","---------Error No Response!!-----");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Here","---------Error-----"+ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Please, add more information, for example, a piece of code where the error occurs.

Comment: Which line gives you the error you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

The url you're specifying is in your sample code is:

```
String url = "myurl";
```

In order for HttpClient to be able to determine the host name, you're going to need to supply a valid url.  Something along the lines of:

```
String url = "http://myurl.com/index";
```

Note:  The 'http://' is important so that the appropriate protocol can be determined.

[This guy](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/04/29/android-odd-error-in-defaulthttpclient/) had the same problem.

Comment: i got the correct uri link.. for better understanding i put it as "myurl"